# Права на установку обновлений Windows простыми пользователями

Tags: windows-8

Есть Windows 8.1 single language.

Обычные пользователи (не администраторы) из коробки наделены возможностью штатными средствами устанавливать апдейты Windows.

Как запретить это всем, кроме пользователей с правами администратора? Существует, вроде, вариант настроить это с помощью групповых политик, но в 8.1 single language - сюрприз! - нет групповых политик.

Answer (score 1):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate
```

Изменить ключ `ElevateNonAdmins dword 0` (Существует вероятность, что `gpedit.msc` нет, а веточка в реестре есть).

Comment: В ветке `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows` нет `WindowsUpdate` =(